# rosbag and parameters dump with unique timestamp in filename

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, rosbag, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
my problem is the following:
I want to save a rosbag file and dump at the same time the content of the parameter server on a file.
I want the file and the rosbag to have exactly the same time appendix.  This is a similar problem to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/213145/use-rosparam-get-in-launch-file/) but not quite the same because it doesn't involve setting the timestamps into parameter server values.

I couldn't find a way to save the timestamp string into an `arg`, however the following code kind of works for the parameters:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="time_now" value="`date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'`" />
  <rosparam command="dump" param="/robot_description" file="robot_description_$(arg time_now).yaml" />
  <node name="rosbag" pkg="rosbag" type="record"
          args="-O robot_$(arg time_now).bag /chatter "/>
</launch>
```

The output says something like:

```
running rosparam dump robot_description_`date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'`.yaml /robot_description
```

but the filename is correct.

However,
when it comes to the rosbag part, the command is not understood, and in particular it believes `+'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'` is a topic to log instead of the argument of `date`.

I know I could exploit the automatic appending of the string from rosbag, but there is a tiny chance the two string would be different.

I've tried to execute a fake node with a bash script inside that sets up an environment variable to be captured with `$(env ...)` but it didn't work out.

I've tried to use python and `$(eval ...)`, but I couldn't get to work because I cant import and use `time` in the same line.

I understood that `param` are inaccessible from a launchfile (you can only set them but not get) unless you do dirty tricks with `launch-prefix`.

Is there another way (please don't tell me the only way is to create a Python script to run the rosbag)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325812/rosbag-and-parameters-dump-with-unique-timestamp-in-filename/) by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2019-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-14**:
I haven't really looked into this, but does this *have to be* started from a `.launch` file? A simple shellscript could do this easily (and shell scripts can be started from `.launch` files as well).

**Comment by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on 2019-06-14**:
you mean, calling the ROS commands (i.e., `rosparam dump`, `rosbag`, etc.)  in a bash script and then calling the bash script from the launchfile? That might work but unfortunately it's a code shared among many people and I'm pretty sure they would not accept such change. Previously the launchfile simply had a fixed name for the yaml files and an appendix for the rosbag node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if there are other constraints surrounding this, but one way is to make the `time_now` argument configurable on the command line:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="time_now" default="temp" />
  <rosparam command="dump" param="/robot_description" file="robot_description_$(arg time_now).yaml" />
  <node name="rosbag" pkg="rosbag" type="record"
        args="-O robot_$(arg time_now).bag /chatter "/>
</launch>
```

and then call it like so (I saved the above in a file called `test.launch`):

```
roslaunch test.launch time_now:=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)
```

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2019-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on 2019-06-20**:
This answer wins. Thanks!